# firebase Not saving data

Tags: firebase

Im using firebase and for some reason my code is not pushing data and im not seeing the data in the firebase url. My code is this

```
var chatref = new Firebase('https://flockedin.firebaseio.com/');
chatref.push({ ChatId: $('#conversationId').text(), User: $('#username').html(), Message: $('#txtchat').val() }, function (response) { if (response) { alert('saved'); } });
```

i get the alert 'saved' but i cant find the data in firebase url.

Also what is the use of API Key that is given for each url in the firebase.

UPDATE:This happens in IE10. In other browsers it works fine

Comment: Currently I see the number 1234 at that location in your Firebase. Perhaps you are overwriting your pushed data with a number and that's why it's not appearing?

Also trying doing a console.log() of the data you're about to push before you do it to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: That is a manual Data that i added

Comment: Ok. Seems it is not working in IE alone. In Chrome it worked like charm

Answer (score 6):

IE10 seems to be working for me. Can you give more details about what version you are using (desktop / tablet / phone?).

Also, is it possible that your jquery selectors were returning null? If all of the values in the object that you set evaluate to null, Firebase treats it like a call to remove. See the note in the docs for set: https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript-client/firebase/set.html

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your FireBase Console->Database->Rules and set them to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Make sure your app is not public when you do this. Lmk if it helps.